# Could not Embed Iframe in CKeditor 3.6.6 with WYSIWIG 7.x

Tags: wysiwyg

am using [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) with CKedior but I am not able to embed iframe into this. I went through many documentations and stack pages but i couldnt find a solution.

> [CKeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_ckeditor) version : 3.6.6.2.7696
>
> [WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) : 7.x-2.2
>
> [Media WYSIWYG](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_mediaembed) : 7.x-2.0-alpha4

Any help will be appreciated .Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried using `Full HTML` format?

Comment: Yes Am using Full HTML

Comment: Check WYSIWYG configuration if `Iframe` is checked? That can be a reason.

Comment: Iframe have to enabled..for proper functionality?

Comment: Give it a try. I never embedded an iframe using textarea. It is a bad practice.

Comment: Sure :) I will try. I know its a bad practice, But situation demands.:)

Comment: Let me know what happens. :)